# Class template argument deduction with a parameter pack in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to implement class template argument deduction on a class. My class is templated over a type `T` ( will be a numeric) and the constructor over a `std::size_t` parameter pack.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <experimental/array>

template < typename T, std::size_t S>
struct my_array
{               
    template < typename ...SizeTypes>
    my_array( SizeTypes&& ... s ):
    data( std::forward<std::array<std::size_t, S>>( std::experimental::make_array<std::size_t>( std::forward<SizeTypes>(s)... ) ) )
    { 
    }

    T value = T();
    std::array<std::size_t, S> data;
};

template <  typename T, class...Dimensions>
my_array( Dimensions&& ... )->my_array<T, sizeof...(Dimensions)>;

int main()
{   
    my_array<double> a(3, 4, 5);
    a.value = 2.32;
    std::cout << a.value << ", " << a.data[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:24:20: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
     my_array<double> a(3, 4, 5);
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VmiPFW9b4MIc9tZY)

Any ideas on how to properly implement this?

Answer (score 4):

`T` is non-deduced context here:

```
template <  typename T, class... Dimensions>
my_array( Dimensions&& ... )->my_array<T, sizeof...(Dimensions)>;
```

Since there's no way to deduce `T`, this deduction guide will never be selected. None of the implicit guides are viable either.

Instead, you should do as the standard library do:

```
template <class T, class... U>
my_array(T, U...) -> my_array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

---

Also, as has been asked many many times before, this is not a thing:

```
my_array<double> a(3, 4, 5);
```

You either deduce *everything* or deduce *nothing*. So this should either be:

```
my_array<double, 3> a(3, 4, 5); // no deduction
my_array            b(3.0, 4, 5); // full deduction, b is also my_array<double, 3>
```

Comment: My understanding is that the deduction you propose would be appropriate if T was the same as the std::array value_type. In my case the std::array type is std::size_t and T is a general numeric type.

Comment: @SteveRodeen I'm not sure why that matters? Regardless, you can change the deduction guide however you want, I'm just providing a model. The point is that everything has to be deducible.

Comment: @SteveRodeen, than your first argument would be `3.0` for double.

Comment: @Barry, of course everything needs to be deducible. I was hoping that I could replace a "make_my_array" function (which can achieve proper deduction like: auto a = make_my_array<double>(2,3,4), with the new deduction rules.

Comment: @SergeyA, Thank you for the response. I believe adopting something like what you propose  would make the interface inconsistent